# Git is failing on Sun Solaris 10

Tags: git, curl, solaris-10

We have some sun Solaris machines were we are trying to clone some remote repositories using `git clone`.

The Git and Curl packages are taken from their respective sites as per the OS.

When I am trying to run following command:

```
git clone <remote-url> <my-install-dir> then I am getting following error

Cloning into '<my-install-dir>'...
warning: templates not found /app/infra/git/share/git-core/templates
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'
```

My Solaris version details are as follows:

```
Solaris 10 10/09 s10s_u8wos_08a SPARC
Copyright 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Use is subject to license terms.
Assembled 16 September 2009
```

Note: We have another machine which is same as this where the git clone was successful.

I have no clue as to what is wrong on this machine.

Comment: Sounds like it was not properly installed after the build.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can you please elaborate on that

Comment: It looks for files under /app/infra/git, which are present on one server, and not on the other.  Sounds like it has been incorrectly installed.  Could you talk to the responsible system administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this issue was happening is that I was not actually intalling the Git rather copying the git.gtar and untaring on the machine and just because the machine did not have /app/infra directory it was failiing. The solution which we came up with is
To create a soft link as below

```
ln -s <install-dir> /app/infra
```